# `regionprops' undefined on Octave

Tags: octave

I would like to use Matlab [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#bqkf8ln) function in Octave.

I am getting **error: `regionprops' undefined**:

```
octave-3.2.4.exe:744> s  = regionprops(Image, 'centroid');
error: `regionprops' undefined near line 744 column 6
```

Is there a way to use it? How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Install the Image package available at http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/index.html